# Store files under 16MB in MongoDB using GridFs is a good idea?

Tags: mongodb, bson, gridfs

I know MongoDB documents only supports up to 16MB. If I want to store files bigger than this value, I should use GridFs. Lower than that, they suggest to use BSON instead.

I have made a test, saving 33000 files with 10MB each, 16500 using BSON and 16500 using GridFs. The result I got for saving and getting the last 10 files using BSON vs GridFs was:

[image: Saving the last 10 files]

And for retrieving the last 10 files I got the following result:

[image: Getting the last 10 files]

Thinking about performance, it seems that using GridFs for files lower than 16MB it is still better than using BSON. So, the **question is**: For saving any file (no matter its size), it is best to use GridFs? Or for files under 16MB, BSON should be used for another reason that I don't know?

Comment: I ask myself the same question today! So based on your experience is it good idea?